# Determining what index to create given a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

Given a SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Database..Pizza pizza
JOIN Database..Toppings toppings ON pizza.ToppingId = toppings.Id
WHERE toppings.Name LIKE '%Mushroom%' AND
toppings.GlutenFree = 0 AND
toppings.ExtraFee = 1.25 AND
pizza.Location = 'Minneapolis, MN'
```

How do you determine what index to write to improve the performance of the query? (Assuming every value to the right of the equal is calculated at runtime)

Is there a built in command SQL command to suggest the proper index?

To me, it gets confusing when there's multiple `JOINS` that use fields from both tables.

Comment: Well if you show the execution plan in SSMS and it thinks there should be a index, it will tell you.

Comment: BTW an alias should be one or 3 characters, part of the point is to shorten the names. So `P` for pizza and `T` for toppings.

Comment: Determining indexes is an entire field of study - I would suggest finding some of the many great articles available on the internet.

Comment: This is also not a programming question and as such belongs on dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Since when is questions about SQL not allowed on Stackoverflow? That was never the case in the past.

Comment: Its not an SQL question, its a database tuning question - and why wouldn't you want to use a site which is entirely dedicated to database questions with the associated level of expertise?

Comment: @KolobCanyon . . . This query suggests that a pizza can have only one topping.  That seems strange.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry my example sucks :(   It should be a one to many relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Database..Pizza p JOIN
     Database..Toppings t
     ON p.ToppingId = t.Id
WHERE t.Name LIKE '%Mushroom%' AND
      t.GlutenFree = 0 AND
      t.ExtraFee = 1.25 AND
      p.Location = 'Minneapolis, MN';
```

You basically have two options for indexes:

- `Pizza(location, ToppingId)` and `Toppings(id)`

or:

- `Toppings(GlutenFree, ExtraFee, Name, id)` and `Pizza(ToppingId, location)`

Which works better depends on how selective the different conditions are in the `WHERE` clause.